# What is the difference between /ʊ/ and /ʌ/ in British English?

Tags: british-english, phonology, phonetics, vowels, ipa

/ʌ/ cut, hut, bun, nothing, love, enough, flood, does

/ʊ/ put, soot, foot, good, look, cook

To me the ʌ is a more short, low front (unrounded?) vowel, but the vowel /ʊ/ which sounds like "uh" is a short, high back (rounded?) vowel but this difference is only minor that you could probably swap each sound when speaking and get away with it.

For example, pronouncing cut as /kʊt/ "kuht", instead of the short /kʌt/ "kut". I can do this with the other words too: hut, bun, nothing, love etc.

**Edit: I'm talking about British English phonology, not American English**...

> For example in AmE, you can say soot in 2 ways (sʊt and su:t ?), [Merriam  Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soot):
>
> \ ˈsu̇t  , ˈsət, ˈsüt  \

Comment: What is your question?  The difference between the two versions is subtle, and generally not critical for speech to be understood.  It's one of many subtleties in English pronunciation.

Comment: Actually, I'd pronounce the vowel sound in your first set of examples several different ways -- "cut" and "love" are different.  (Just not as different as "cut' and "put".)

Comment: @Hot Licks I am learning the IPA, I'm asking what the **difference** is because they are vowels which have been assigned different phonetic symbols. Detecting why and how they are different, is the job of phoneticians which is why I tagged it as 'phonology'. However, I can't detect the 'subtleness' which I why I asked this question.

Comment: The difference is not subtle *at all*. If it is subtle for you, you're a native speaker of a very particular dialect.

Comment: In most American dialects, /ʊ/ is high, back, lax, and rounded; it has a limited distribution, appearing only in stressed syllables. [ʌ] is the allophone of the central phoneme /ə/ that occurs in stressed syllables; it's mid, central, lax, and unrounded. The biggest difference between them in American English is that you round your lips a bit to say [ʊ] and you don't round them to say [ʌ]; that's visible in a mirror.

Comment: Can you tell the difference between putt/put? Have you checked the wikipedia pages for these two vowels? [Open-mid back unrounded vowel /ʌ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_unrounded_vowel) [Near-close back rounded vowel /ʊ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-close_back_rounded_vowel)

Comment: @ukemi root, hoot, boot,  toot etc all have the /u:/ phoneme, not the /ʊ/.

Comment: @Rattler ah, in my dialect they've merged: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_close_back_vowels#Foot–goose_merger

Comment: @ukemi Yes I can tell the difference between short ʌ (hut) and long vowel u: (hoot), but not the difference between ʊ/ʌ against long vowel u:

Comment: The difference between these pairs is not very subtle to my (pretty standard American) ear: putt/put, luck/look, cud/could, pus/puss. If your native language doesn't have both of these vowels, it's not unusual that you can't differentiate between them, but that's a limitation of your ear, rather than the IPA

Comment: @JohnLawler What about in British English? Sorry I should have made it more clearer that my background was British and so I can't relate to the American differences. For example, I think you guys say god as /ɡɑːd/, instead of /ɡɒd/.

Comment: For /ʊ/ sound, my tongue is close to the top and near the back of my mouth and my lips are rounded. 
I produce */u:/* and */ʊ/* exactly the same way but /u:/ is longer than /ʊ/..

When I produce */ʌ/*, my tongue is *not* close to the top of my mouth and my lips are not rounded.
(In some dialects, they might be the same.)

Comment: Lots of British people say bʊtter rather than bʌtter, but they tend to live in the North, and are instantly recognisable as northeners. Historically this pronunciation was considered inferior and unrefined or even uneducated; today we are more tolerant.

Comment: In some British English dialects "nothing" is pronounced with an ɒ vowel (like British English "pot"). Also in some dialects (e.g. the Manchester area) soot, cook, book are pronounced with a long uː vowel.

Comment: What dialect of British English? The various dialects are all about as different from each other as AmE is from each of them.

Comment: In Yorkshire, all the example words in the OP have exactly the same vowel sound. They are not differentiated at all. Look = luck. By the time you get down to London, you've got possibly 4 different sounds in the same list.

Comment: I think that the suggestion of  /ʌ/ cut, hut, bun, and /ʊ/ put, soot, foot, good is a counsel of perfection and unlikely to be adhered to in any real-world situation.

Comment: *"you could probably swap each sound when speaking and get away with it."*. No, you cannot switch each sound and 'get away with it' in any dialect of English. In your examples (put, cut etc.) the vocalised 'u' sounds need to reflect their standardized pronunciations to make sense i.e. you need to pronounce clearly the /ʌ/ or /ʊ/ sounds to avoid confusion and make sense. I hadn't thought about it before, but in this case, the difference between the sounds are very important.

Answer (score 10):

The sounds of /ʌ/ and /ʊ/ are only moderately similar from a strictly phonetic point of view. However, in the context of phonology, you might feel like the difference is "[so] minor that you could probably swap each sound when speaking and get away with it" for a couple of reasons:

- the contrast has a low "functional load": in accents affected by the [foot-strut split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_close_back_vowels#FOOT%E2%80%93STRUT_split),* /ʊ/ is a rare sound, and there are only a few pairs of words, such as *buck* and *book,* that are distinguished solely by the use of /ʌ/ vs /ʊ/. (In other dialects, the same pair of words are sometimes distinguished differently by the use of /ʊ/ vs /uː/.)
- In some fairly widespread British English dialects, /ʌ/ is not normally used and words that have /ʌ/ in standard English instead have /ʊ/.

*This includes so-called "Received Pronunciation", [Southern British English](https://swphonetics.com/articulation/accents/sbe/), and North American English accents.

Comment: I would suggest using "received pronunciation" which is the correct term for what you call "standard English", as there isn't really a standard English. Alternatively be specific which dialects you mean (ie dialects of Southern England by and large use /ʌ/ and those elsewhere in the UK by and large don't).

Answer (score 2):

In my accent (Yorkshire English), the words listed in the two categories above are pronounced exactly the same. Cut rhymes with put, hut with soot, etc.

Comment: Would you say *luck* and *look* are the same?

Comment: @GEdgar Presumably for them they are, yes: [“The FOOT– STRUT split is the split of Middle English short /u/ into two distinct phonemes: /ʊ/ (as in foot) and /ʌ/ (as in strut). The split occurs in most varieties of English, the most notable exceptions being most of Northern England and the English Midlands and some varieties of Hiberno-English.”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_close_back_vowels#FOOT%E2%80%93STRUT_split) I actually happen to work with (a few) people who lack the FOOT–STRUT split.